# How to invert first order differencing in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, inverse

I want to know an easy and efficient method to invert first order (lag 1) linear differenced data in python. I have a multivariate TS with 3 exog variables a, b and c. Though there are several blogs on inverse function, but seems all targeted to complex scenario and I am unable to find some help to my problem which is not that complex. I am new to python and writing a paper for my academic work. So, want to reach out to the community for a easy solution.

I am using vector auto regression model for prediction purpose. If there is anything wrong with my below coding, kindly suggest otherwise.

```
diff = originaldata.diff().dropna() 


model = VAR(diff)
result = model.fit()
fcast = result.forecast(diff.values[-1:], steps=2)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(fcast, index=originaldata.index[-2:], 
columns = originaldata.columns
```

Should I take the cumulative sum to roll-back the differencing considering cumulatively add the difference-forecasts to the last cumulative observation?

```
fcast_cs = dataframe.cumsum()
```

also how do I use the inverse function here to get back to the original form?

Answer (score 0):

```
def invert_transformation(df_train, df_forecast, second_diff=False):
    """Revert back the differencing to get the forecast to original scale."""
    df_fc = df_forecast.copy()
    columns = df_train.columns
    for col in columns:        
        # Roll back 2nd Diff
        if second_diff:
            df_fc[str(col)+'_1d'] = (df_train[col].iloc[-1]-df_train[col].iloc[-2]) + df_fc[str(col)+'_2d'].cumsum()
        # Roll back 1st Diff
        df_fc[str(col)+'_forecast'] = df_train[col].iloc[-1] + df_fc[str(col)+'_1d'].cumsum()
    return df_fc
```

[refer link](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/vector-autoregression-examples-python/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).